# Primefaces p:fileupload oncomplete does not work in IE 10

Tags: ajax, file-upload, primefaces

I use primefaces + jsf web project.

In index.xhtml JS:

```js
function showStatus() {
    statusDialog.show();
}

function hideStatus() {
    statusDialog.hide();
}
```

In index.xhtml PF:

```html
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();"
            onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />
            
<p:fileUpload label="#{msg['cms']['selectFile']}"
            uploadLabel="#{msg['cms']['upload']}"
            mode="advanced" multiple="true"
            cancelLabel="#{msg['framework']['cancel']}"
            fileUploadListener="#{storageController.handleMultipleFileUpload}">
</p:fileUpload>
```

When I trigger an AJAX call through `<p:commandButton`, the `<p:ajaxStatus` does not work, but still shows the following loading image:

[image]

It should hide the `statusDialog` when file upload is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request Context to update your form in the fileUploadListener of the fileUpload component. Thus after the file has been uploaded you can manually refresh the form to show the updated table or anything else on the form.